# Python pandas add column with values based on condition and pattern

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

My python pandas dataframe originally using openpyxl engine to handle excel processing, 
can be described in simple form as

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["",99,88,np.nan,66,55,np.nan,11,22],"col2":['Catg0','Asset1','Other','Catg1','H & F','Large Item','Catg2','Fragile','Delicate item'],"col3":["",0,0,np.nan,99,155,np.nan,83,115]})

  col1           col2 col3
0               Catg0
1   99         Asset1    0
2   88          Other    0
3  NaN          Catg1  NaN
4   66          H & F   99
5   55     Large Item  155
6  NaN          Catg2  NaN
7   11        Fragile   83
8   22  Delicate item  115
```

While I am trying it to get modified further with having new column (col4) by pivoting value from other column (col2) when other of the column data is empty or nan for that row, untill next such condition satiesfies
It should remove that row after pivoting

```
   col1   col4           col2  col3
0    99  Catg0         Asset1     0
1    88  Catg0          Other     0
2    66  Catg1          H & F    99
3    55  Catg1     Large Item   155
4    11  Catg2        Fragile    83
5    22  Catg2  Delicate item   115

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1":["",99,88,np.nan,66,55,np.nan,11,22],"col2":['Catg0','Asset1','Other','Catg1','H & F','Large Item','Catg2','Fragile','Delicate item'],"col3":["",0,0,np.nan,99,155,np.nan,83,115]})
df1.insert(1, "col4", 'Catg')
```

I am trying to find way to add these pattern or conditin based logic to populate 'col4' and discard that rows

Answer (score 1):

You can identify empty or `nan`s by all columns without `col2` first by [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) for remove column, replace `NaN`s and test empty strings if all another columns by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), then add [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) with forward filling missing values for repeat categories and last filter out this rows in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df1.drop('col2', axis=1).fillna('').eq('').all(axis=1)
df1.insert(1, "col4", df1['col2'].where(m).ffill())

out = df1[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
print (out)
  col1   col4           col2 col3
0   99  Catg0         Asset1    0
1   88  Catg0          Other    0
2   66  Catg1          H & F   99
3   55  Catg1     Large Item  155
4   11  Catg2        Fragile   83
5   22  Catg2  Delicate item  115
```

Another approach is get `col2` values with pattern - e.g. here starting by `Catg` with numeric:

```
m = df1['col2'].str.contains('^Catg\d+$')
df1.insert(1, "col4", df1['col2'].where(m).ffill())

out = df1[~m].reset_index(drop=True)
print (out)
  col1   col4           col2 col3
0   99  Catg0         Asset1    0
1   88  Catg0          Other    0
2   66  Catg1          H & F   99
3   55  Catg1     Large Item  155
4   11  Catg2        Fragile   83
5   22  Catg2  Delicate item  115
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution, which uses [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to define groups and then uses [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to modify the grouped dataframes:

```
(df1.assign(grp = (df1['col3'].isna() | df1['col3'].eq('')).cumsum())
 .groupby('grp', as_index = False)
 .apply(lambda x: x.tail(len(x)-1)
        .assign(col4 = x.head(1)['col2'].tolist() * (len(x)-1)))
 .reset_index(drop = True)[['col1','col4','col2','col3']])
```

Output:

```
  col1   col4           col2 col3
0   99  Catg0         Asset1    0
1   88  Catg0          Other    0
2   66  Catg1          H & F   99
3   55  Catg1     Large Item  155
4   11  Catg2        Fragile   83
5   22  Catg2  Delicate item  115
```

Comment: Thank you PaulS, I will try this as well for my use case